# C++ : how can I define an array type customers in a class name careercenter then define create, modify and delete in .cpp file

Tags: c++

I have to write a project program in c++ using Dev.
I start to write it and it goes very will when suddenly I found myself stuck in it.
the question was :

The aim of this project is to develop a C++ program that supports a careers centre using objectoriented
concepts. The careers centre has a name, and two kinds of customers, individual
customers seeking employment and companies offering jobs. For each individual customer a
customer id, a name, an address, a phone number, and a date of birth are stored. Each company
customer has a customer id, a name, and an address. Moreover, the company has an employee
who is the contact point for the job agency. Companies advertise job vacancies that consist of a
job id, a job title, the salary offered, and the date when an employee can start on the job. The
companies can create, modify, and delete job. The careers centre stores the customers in an array
and can create, modify, and delete customer.

.h file

```
 #ifndef CAREER.H
#define CAREER.H

class careercenter
{
    public:
        careercenter(string);
        ~careercenter();
        customers*cu[100];
        int count=0;
        createCustomers();
        modifyCustomers();
        deleteCustomers();
        string getCareerName();
        void setCareerName(string);
        void print();
    private:
        string careername;
};

class customers
{
    public:
        customers(int,string,string);
        ~customers();
        int getCusId();
        string getCusName();
        string getCusAdress();
        void setCusId(int);
        void setCusName(string);
        void setCusAdress(string);
        void print();
    private:
        int CusId;
        string CusName;
        sting CusAdress;
};

class individual : public customers
{
    public:
        individual(int,string,string,int,int);
        ~individual();
        int getIndPhone();
        int getIndDate();
        void setIndPhone(int);
        void setIndDate(int);
        void print();
    private:
        int indPhone;
        int indDate
};


class company : public customers
{
    public:
        company(int,string,string,int,string);
        ~company();
        int getEmpName();
        job jobs[10];
        int count=0;
        createJob();
        modifyJob();
        deleteJob();
        string getEmpAdress();
        void setEmpName(string);
        void setEmpAdress(string);
        void print();
    private:
        string empName;
        string empAdress;
};

class job
{
    public:
        job(int,string,double,int);
        ~job();
        int getJobId();
        sting getJobTitle();
        double getJobSalary();
        int getJobDateStart();
        void setJobId(int);
        void setJobTitle(string);
        void setJobSalary(double);
        void setJobDateStart(int);
        void print();
    private:
        int jobId;
        string jobTitle;
        double jobSalary;
        int jobDateStart;

};


#endif
```

.cpp file

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include"career.h"

//careercenter class

careercenter::careercenter(string CarName)
{
    setCareerName(CarName);
}

careercenter::~careercenter()
{
}

careercenter::createCustomers()
{                               
}

careercenter::modifyCustomers()
{                               
}

careercenter::deleteCustomers()
{                               
}

string careercenter::getCareerName()
{
    return careername;
}

void careercenter::setCareerName(string Carname)
{
    careername=CarName;
}

void careercenter::print()
{
    cout<<careername;
}

//customers class

customers::customers(int CuId , string CuName, string CuAdress)
{
    setCusId(CuId);
    setCusName(CuName);
    setCusAdress(CuAdress);
}

customers::~careercenter()
{
}

int customers::getCusId()
{
    return CusId;
}

string customers::getCusName()
{
    return CusName;
}

string customers::getCusAdress()
{
    return CusAdress;
}

void customers::setCusId(int CuId)
{
    CusId=CuId;
}

void customers::setCusName(string CuName)
{
    CusName=CuName;
}

void customers::setCusAdress(string Carname)
{
    CusAdress=CuAdress;
}

void customers::print()
{
    cout<<CusId<<endl<<CusName<<CusAdress<endl;
}

//individual : public customers

individual::individual(int CuId , string CuName, string CuAdress, int InPhone, int InDate):customers(CuId,CuName,CuAdress),indPhone(InPhone),indDate(InDate)
{
}

individual::~individual()
{
}

int individual::getIndPhone()
{
    return indPhone;
}

int individual::getIndDate()
{
    return indDate;
}

void individual::setIndPhone(int InPhone)
{
    indPhone=InPhone;
}

void individual::setIndDate(int InDate)
{
    indDate=InDate;
}

void individual::print()
{
    point::print();
    cout<<"HI"<<endl;
}

//company : public customers

company::company(int CuId , string CuName, string CuAdress,string EmName, string EmAdress):customers(CuId,CuName,CuAdress),empName(EmName),empAdress(EmAdress)
{
}

company::~company()
{
}

careercenter::createJob()
{                               
}

careercenter::modifyJob()
{                               
}

careercenter::deleteJob()
{                               
}

string company::getEmpName()
{
    return empName;
}

string company::getEmpAdress()
{
    return empAdress;
}

void company::setEmpName(string EmName)
{
    empName=EmName;
}

void company::setEmpAdress(string EmAdress)
{
    empAdress=EmAdress;
}

void company::print()
{
    point::print();
    cout<<"HI"<<endl;
}

//job class

job::job(int JoId,string JoTitle,double JoSalary,int JoDateStart)
{
    setJobId(JoId);
    setJobTitle(JoTitle);
    setJobSalary(JoSalary);
    setJobDateStart(JoDateStart);
}

job::~job()
{
}

int job::getJobId()
{
    return jobId;
}

string job::getJobTitle()
{
    return jobTitle;
}

double job::getJobSalary()
{
    return jobSalary;
}

int job::getJobDateStart()
{
    return jobDateStart;
}

void job::setJobId(int JoId)
{
    jobId=JoId;
}

void job::setJobTitle(string JoTitle)
{
    jobTitle=JoTitle;
}

void job::setJobSalary(double JoSalary)
{
    jobSalary=JoSalary;
}

void job::setJobDateStart(int JoDateStart)
{
    jobDateStart=JoDateStart;
}

void job::print()
{
    cout<<jobId<<endl<<jobTitle<<endl<<jobSalary<<endl<<jobDateStart<<endl;
}
```

I wrote my .h file and .cpp file , but I don't know how I can define an array type customers in careercenter class in the .cpp file.

I don't know how to define create, modify and delete customers and jobs in .cpp file.
I want when the user enter 1 the program take him to individual class, and 2 to company class.

Comment: I wish companies could create customer out of thin air

Comment: Please try to include a [Short Self Contained Correct/Compilable Example - SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: please capitalize your classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea would be to use one of the stl containers, std::list would be fine: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/ . **You may use associative container like std::map to access customer by its unique name.**

Moreover individual customers should be notified when a company customer advertises some job (so I presume). Observer design pattern would do the trick: http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html